# Mockito anyListOf: results being overridden with different instances as parameters

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to use mockito to return different results based on the type of the list elements.

lets say that i want different results on the following service method:

```
public class MyService {
   MyBean createBean(List<? extends A>, Report report) {
       //some super code
   } 
}

public interface A {

}

public class B implements A {

}

public class C implements A {

}

public Report {
    public List<B> bList;
    public List<C> cList;

    //getters and setters
}
```

the method createBean(..) is on a class that is under test, and i want to make sure when invoked it is invoked with the correct list. So i created the following mocked results:

```
doReturn(createBean01()).when(myService).createBean(anyListOf(B.class), any(Report.class));
doReturn(createBean02()).when(myService).createBean(anyListOf(C.class), any(Report.class));
```

I was expecting that Bean01 is returned when the createBean method is invoked with a list with elements of type B, and Bean02 when inkoved with a list with elements of type C.

I tried as well with the specific instances of the lists the but behaviour was the same.

```
doReturn(createBean01()).when(myService).createBean(report.getBList(),report);
doReturn(createBean02()).when(myService).createBean(report.getCList(),report);
```

It looks like the behaviour is being overriden. Is like Mockito does not distinguish the subtypes.

What is missing me? How can can I have different results types based on the type of the lists?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature.  You are expecting a runtime feature.  That will not work.

Comment: DwB, you might have a point. Would this be the reason why anyOfList will be deprecated and only anyList() will be available?

Comment: The main reason for the new methods like `any()` versus `any(Class)` is that the Java8 compiler is better at *type inference*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting mocking wrong. You use mocking specification to express / configure the specific setup for a specific test.

What I mean is: besides the fact that generics are *erased* at runtime and you (normally) do not know the specific generic type that was used when creating a list - you really don't want that your test code does something *based* on parameters given to a mock object.

In other words: write down your tests as specific as possible, like:

```
@Test
public void testWithA() {
  when(myService.createBean(someListOfBs)).thenReturn(someResultA);
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Test
public void testWithB() {
  when(myService.createBean(someListOfBs)).thenReturn(somethingElse);
  ...
}
```

Meaning: use mocking specifications as that - as a spec that tells the mocking framework how it should behave. Avoid getting into the business of having *sophisticated* logic around those specs!

And hint: you should prefer when().then() over doAnswer().when(). You only use the later one for those rare cases when the more strict *type checking* that option 1 gives ... doesn't work for your test scenario.

Comment: by mistake i unvoted your comment. Is there a way to undo the unvote?

Comment: @mpssantos Never mind. You *upvoted* the comment. That is nothing bad. No effects whatsoever. And normally I delete those anyway. But if you really feel bad about that, just turn to my profile and upvote some of my *answers*. That will make me feel great, and then you might feel much better as well ;-)